# On our own rococo staging chain is it possible to bypass the long onboarding process for parachains, with Sudo?

Tags: validator, rococo-local, polkadot-local

I'm running a rococo style relay chain with other community members. It can take more than 3 hours to upgrade to parathread and then from parathread to parachain.

Is there a sudo extrinsic i am missing to bypass the onboarding process, where the onboarding time can be reduced?

Answer (score 2):

> It takes 2 sessions for the chain to fully onboard as a parathread.

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/#register-as-a-parathread

Answer (score 2):

You can compile polkadot with `--features fast-runtime` and most actions (onboarding, democracy) will require a lot less time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paras.forceQueueAction(paraId)` to make the onboarding happen in the very next session.
I am afraid that this is the only and fastest way that I know to make this process faster.

I don't have all the details, but have into account that a new para will need a new subset of validators. And if you check the definition on `Session`

- > Session: A session is a period of time that has a constant set of
  > validators. Validators can only join or exit the validator set at a
  > session change

For me it is clear that you cannot go faster than one session when oboarding paras.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L774

Comment: Ok so reducing the session time seems like the only way to reduce the onboarding time.

Answer (score 0):

Developer -> Sudo

1. `parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize(paraId, genesis)`.
   This step will onboard the parathread
   [image: init]
2. `slots.forceLease(paraId, leaser, amount, periodBegin, periodCount)`.
   This step will give the parathread lease and upgrade it to parachain, if not upgrade, you can do it via `parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParathreadUpgrade(paraId)`
   [image: upgradeparachain]